# How to copy web files to Linux machine...?

Tags: linux, shell

What is the shell command to do this action.

"Copy the file `https://improvement.abc.com/s3hkfiles/snbget.cgi/szubjkrgotc-xpra.repo` to `/etc/yujhkm.rmepos.d`"

Comment: `wget https://improvement.abc.com/s3hkfiles/snbget.cgi/szubjkrgotc-xpra.repo -P /etc/yujhkm.rmepos.d` if the latter is a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `wget`.  Try this:

```
$ wget https://improvement.abc.com/s3hkfiles/snbget.cgi/szubjkrgotc-xpra.repo
```

Comment: Glad it helped.  Please up-vote!

Comment: Remember to quote the URL in single quotes, in case the URL contains characters like `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Curl and sudo is one possibility:

```
curl -O 'https://improvement.abc.com/s3hkfiles/snbget.cgi/szubjkrgotc-xpra.repo'
sudo cp -i -v szubjkrgotc-xpra.repo /etc/yujhkm.rmepos.d
```

Another way is to download it directly, but downloading anything as root is not recommended at all, because of possible security implications:

```
sudo curl -o /etc/yujhkm.rmepos.d 'https://improvement.abc.com/s3hkfiles/snbget.cgi/szubjkrgotc-xpra.repo'
```